# any ideas for count job on hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

we are having issues some issues in our data stored in hive. we have more than 50 tables that has PB of data. In order to fix the issue, we are taking hive count and then analyzing the issues. so, i have to spend around 2-3 hours approximately everyday for count job since our tables are huge.
I am just wondering if there is any tools/application or ideas to reduce the amount of time to spend for count job.
I could not find anything in google about this.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options -

1. if you want correct and actual count, you can use pyspark or spark. Use count like `select count(1) from mytable` and do not use count(*).
   But this can give you perf problem if you have table of PB size.
2. if you want somewhat close count, you can use `show table stats mytab`, this shows rowcount (#Rows). If your hive system is set to gather table stats daily/regularly, you will get a count which is close to the actual count. If your table is partitioned, you need to add all partitions up.